# Butterknife binding outside of activity

Tags: android, butterknife

How to use binding with activity?

```
public class MyViewController extends BaseViewController<MyActivity> {

    @BindView(R.id.view_pager)
    ViewPager viewPager;

    public void bindViews() {
        //bind(@NonNull Object target, @NonNull Activity source)
        ButterKnife.bind(this, activity);
    }  
}
```

looks good. But my application crashes within generated code:

```
    protected InnerUnbinder(final T target, Finder finder, Object source) {
    ...
          target.viewPager = finder.findRequiredViewAsType(source, 2131558529, "field 'viewPager'", ViewPager.class);
    ...
}
```

where butterknife.internal.Finder.findRequiredViewAsType is

```
public final <T> T findRequiredViewAsType(Object source, int id, String who, Class<T> cls) {
    View view = findRequiredView(source, id, who);
    try {
      return cls.cast(view);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      String name = getResourceEntryName(view, id);
      throw new IllegalStateException("View '"
          + name
          + "' with ID "
          + id
          + " for "
          + who
          + " was of the wrong type. See cause for more info.", e);
    }
```

Because "Object source" is Activity, but not View, my application will crash with Class Cast Exception.

I have only one idea how to bind views outside of activity: send myActivity.findViwById(R.id.activity_root_view) as second parameter for binder (works fine). And I think, that this method should works fine without this uglycode. What do you think, where am I wrong?

Butterknife 8.1.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Why are you binding view in Presenter. it should be done either in Activity or Fragment

Comment: why do you need a `viewPager` to be a part of your presenter? I though it is part of `View`

Comment: you right, this is view part, not presenter, Ill refactor it. I use activities and fragments only as view container with navigation/state logic, and all view-logic moved into another classes. but the question for the other.

Comment: If your goal is just to bind views on a activity than you should call `ButterKnife.bind(this);` right after you set the content of your activity on `onCreate`

Comment: I don't think anyone here is getting to the heart of the question, it would be nice to be able to bind views outside of an Activity/Fragment for those who would like to be less dependent on the Android Framework

Answer (score 0):

The problem I ran into is that I had two different views that had the same identifier.  So I just renamed them and this went away.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/902